# Rails sunspot exclude keywords in field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have the following configuration set up for searching in solr...

## controller

```
users = users.search do
                without(:name, 'admin')
                with(:retired, false)
                fulltext(params[:q])
                paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 5
              end
 @users = users.results
```

## model

```
searchable do
    text :name
    boolean :retired
  end
```

I am trying to exclude users who have 'admin' anywhere in the 'name' field. I am getting the error:

`No field configured for Learner with name 'name'`

Ideas?

The name field is valid, and if I remove the 'without' line it works without issue.

Comment: Just an update on this. I am interpreting `Fields not defined as text (e.g., integer, boolean, time, etc...) can be used to scope (restrict) queries before full-text matching is performed.` on https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot to mean `without` can NOT be used on text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude 'admin' name in searchable block

```
searchable do 
  text(:name) { |n| n.name != 'admin' } 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex, but this does not seem to work. I don't get any results returned if I replace `text :name` with `text(:name) { |n| n.name != 'admin' }`

Comment: Try to add one more condition
text(:name) { |n| n.name if n.name != 'admin' }